# How to access a rar file without password

Tags: rar

So I have this very, very old rar file that my uncle compressed. And now he has passed away. So the problem is, it has a password. He told me that the file is for me but he never told me the password. It is the only thing I have that reminds me of him and I would like to know if there is a way to bypass the password from the rar file.

I would love some help.

:|

Answer (score 1):

You could use [RarCrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/) to brute-force the file.

Depending on the password strength an your computers processing power this might take somewhere between very long and almost forever, though. I think I read somewhere that passwords with eight and more characters are too much even for the NSA since it's simply not worth it spending so much time running big machines for that little file.

Sadly, that's pretty much all you got.

Comment: when i do `rarcrack pm.rar --threads 2 --type rar` , i get `INFO: the specified archive type: rar
INFO: cracking pm.rar, status file: pm.rar.xml
INFO: Resuming cracking from password: '2'
GOOD: This archive was succesfully cracked
      The good password is: '0'
ERROR: The status file (pm.rar.xml) is corrupted!`

Comment: Ah, I know. RarCrack doesn't work with unrar. You will have to purge it with `sudo apt-get remove --purge unrar` and install it after using RarCrack again, because else you can't open the file.

Comment: If you knew some details about the password like only numbers or no uppercase letters you could save time massively. At first run terminate quickly and alter the created `pm.rar.xml` file removing unused chars in `<abc>`...`</abc>`. If you knew the minimum password length you could also set `<current>`...`</current>` to `<current>`(passwordlength * `0`)`</current>`. I guess you don't know anything like that.